# scaffold database in azure function 2 app I get build failed error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, entity-framework-core-2.1

I am trying to scaffold my database using ef core trying to use EF to return json data back to my client so I followed this [tutorial](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/existing-database) on how to do the scaffold and I get build failed.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=mydb;Initial Catalog=KP;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myid;Password=mypass;MultipleActiveResultSets=true; Connection Timeout=200;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Entities -Context "KMSContext" -DataAnnotations
```

If I was able to do this how would I handle dependency injection using ef core with azure functions 2 is really new to me

Comment: How did you solve this issue?